# milk chocolate brownie turned out hard and very chewy

Tags: brownies

I made milk chocolate brownie today, intended for a 9x9 inch pan, but in a 8x8 inch pan.  Although I have made these brownies before and they were perfect but did not know what went wrong today. The recipe requires melting milk chocolate and butter together in double pan. Maybe I mixed hot chocolate mixture in the rest of the ingredients. Dont know what went wrong. Can you tell why the brownie texture was hard and chewy like candy?

The recipe calls for melting 1/2 cup butter and 4oz chocolate indirectly. Mixing up 3/4 cup sugar 2 eggs, vanilla and then pour in chocolate mixture when it cools down. One thing I did different was that I did not let the milk chocolate and butter to cool down properly. Then blending in dry ingredients. And remaining 4oz milk chocolate in the mixture. Secondly this time I didn't put the batter immediately in the oven. I had some work so it took me ten or more minutes. The cake was very crunchy. I usually use 8 by 8 circular pan but this time I used a larger square pan

Comment: We are going to need the full recipe and process if we're going to help you. Since you've had success in the past, can you think a bit more about anything that could have been different?

Comment: What pan did you use?

Comment: Hello Zukhraf, our site has a strict one question - many answers format, and each new post has to be an answer, not something else. When you wish to clarify your question, you can use the small grey "edit" link on the left side under the text. I edited the information which you posted as an answer into the body of your question.  Self-answering is preserved for when you find out the solution to your problem yourself and want to share it with others. I also did not quite understand if you used a 9x9 inch or 8x8 inch pan, you can edit that if I got it wrong.

Comment: It is likely that skipping the cooling step is the problem. The more you cook sugar, the harder and more candy-like it gets. There is a good possibility that the sugar in the chocolate ended up being over-cooked because it was not allowed to cool before you proceeded with the recipe.